# LinkedIn follow button language issue

Tags: javascript, localization, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the LinkedIn "follow" button to display in other languages on my site, which already does a lot of localization based on the browser settings, and I've noticed that the LinkedIn API seems to not accept language codes that are "simple", i.e. 2 letters like "fr".  It seems to only want codes like "fr_FR".  with "fr" i see an error like:

```
 'fr' is not a supported language, defaulting to 'en_US'
```

This is not acceptable, since many users may just pick a language without a specific country variant, because many (all?) browsers allow this.

What's an easy way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be a programmatic method to fake a  ISO3166 code if there's only 2 letters in the browser's languages-accepted setting. But I don't think there's a way to always be correct, although it looks like with major languages there seems to be a corresponding ISO3166 country code identical to the language (fr_FR, de_DE, es_ES - but, interestingly: no en_EN ). So I guess the hack way would be to just add the underscore and the uppercase version of the 2 letters, if they're not there already, and let it break and default to US english for those languages that don't have a variant like that. But, I'd rather do better.

It's unfortunate LinkedIn's API is acting this way, since the standards seem to clearly state that the country/region code is optional. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag